# Why v-bind:class not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm learning v-bind:class in VueJS but I've encountered some problems with it. Here are my code

```js
var myApp = new Vue({
  el: "#result",
  data: {
    isActive: true
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
  <p v-bind:class="{red: isActive}">Hello</p>
</div>
```

Was there any problems with my code above? As I want the result to be

```
<div class="red"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have converted your code into  a snippet, see its working

Comment: If you want the class bonding on the div add `v-bind:class` on the div not the <p>. See https://jsfiddle.net/e760kqhj/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = new Vue({
  el: "#result",
  data: function(){
    return {
      isActive: true
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
  <div v-bind:class="{red: isActive}">Hello</div>
</div>
```

---

Data only accepts Function when used in a component definition.

```
data: function(){
    return {
        isActive: true
    }
}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data

Comment: This does not work and is not what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please Run this code on JsFiddle Online Editor.
[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/264176/)

```
<div id="app">
   <div class="box" :class="{bgColor: attache}" @click="attache = !attache">
     <p class="text" :class="{'txt-color': attache}">
       3
     </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.box {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: green;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
  font-size:18px;
  color: white;
}

.bgColor {
  background-color: #e8eaed;
}

.txt-color {
  color: #000;
}
```

JavaScript

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    attache: false
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear you `cache` it will work perfectly.

Check it in Browser Incognito Mode.